# rails wicked gem cancel and clean up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

The Wicked gem is "pretty cool" but I wish it didn't save models until the last step.

Since it does save models and I'm storing intermediate state in the session, I need the ability to allow users to cancel the wizard and have the wizard clean up whats its done.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [solution described in the wicked wiki](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-objects-without-saving-to-the-database)

This solution saves your data into the session until you reach the last, successfull step. Otherwise you can click a 'Cancel' button which will redirect you to the first step and cleanup the session data as described in the wiki.